# Trying to make a tkinter menu button that do multiple tasks

Tags: python, tkinter

I've been trying to make a button in menu bar in the tkinter app and can't seem to figure out how to make this button make multiple tasks. I've tried the following, it forgets the frame correctly but don't execute the carr function.

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

menu_bar = Menu(root)
file_menu = Menu(menu_bar, tearoff = 0)
file_menu.add_command(label="Carré", command=lambda:[frame.pack_forget(),carr])
menu_bar.add_cascade(label="Séléction", menu=file_menu)
root.config(menu=menu_bar)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: If you need to do several things, just write a function.  Don't try to hack a lambda.  And remember that `carr` just gives you the function object.  If you want to call it, you need parens:  `carr()`.

Answer (score 0):

The proper solution is to create a function for the button.

```
def do_carr():
    frame.pack_forget()
    carr()
...
file_menu.add_command(label="Carré", command=do_carr)
```